# Select Data based on From Year and Month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following columns:

```
ID | FromYear | FromMonth | ToYear | ToMonth | Details

1  |  2012    |    5      | 2012   |   7     |  xxx

1  |  2012    |    8      | 2013   |   2     |  yyy

1  |  2013    |    3      |  0     |   0     |  zzz
```

I have two search parameters - Year and Month 
If I search with 2012 and 6, first row should  come and if I search with 2013 and 1
the second row should come... 
Also there is 0 value in To Year and To Month in the last row which indicates it is the highest
dated record, so any record searched with 2013, 3 or more should give the third row**strong text**

Comment: So, your question is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need something like this

```
SELECT
ID,FromYear, FromMonth,ToYear,ToMonth, Details
FROM <tablename>
WHERE --FromYear & FromMonth before or the same as parameters
(
    (FromYear = @year AND FromMonth <= @month)  -- Same year, Earlier Month than parameters
    OR 
    FromYear < @year                            -- Earlier Year than parameter
)
AND --ToYear & ToMonth after or the same as parameters (or both zero)
(
    (ToYear= @year AND ToMonth >= @month) -- Same Year, Later Month than parameters
    OR
    ToYear > @year                         -- Later Year than parameter
    OR
    (ToYear= 0 AND ToMonth = 0)           -- ToYear,ToMonth are zero
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two variables @SearchYear and @SearchMonth ...

```
select *
from YourTableName
where @SearchYear >= FromYear 
    and @SearchYear <= ToYear
    and @SearchMonth >= FromMonth
    and (@SearchMonth <= ToMonth or ToMonth = 0)
```